# Finding the table name of a given value

Tags: mysql

I need some help.

In my database are **serveral tables with details of products**, each product has a unique ID.

Now I have a given product ID - **how can I get the name of the table** in which the product is stored, hence there are different tables in my database? How could I store the table_name in a PHP variable to reuse it in another select-statement?

I search on stackoverflow but found only answers about getting all table_names of a database or columns names. I am looking for a simple solution in a mysql/pdo select statement.

Thanks for an advice!

Comment: Do you mean a fixed set of tables, or dynamically generated tables? (The obvious fix is to have a master table, whatever the design, but we surely need a little bit of context).

Comment: Hi! It is a fixed set of tables in my database. I just need to retrieve the name of the table where my given value (e.g. $id=12345) is stored, very simple. The proplem is I have no clue where to start. I read about the table_name variable in SELECT statements. I need something like

SELECT table_name WHERE ID = $id EXISTS IN COLUMN 'productxyz'

Comment: Is the column name that holds the product always called the same name?

Comment: Yes. I have e.g. 4 tables for different product classes with different details (number of columns, names of columns). But the name of the ID-Column is always the same in all 4 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search in a fixed set of tables, you can combine the individual queries using the `UNION` clause and then add a hard-coded string to identify the source:

```
SELECT packaging_id AS product_id, 'packaging' AS table_name
FROM packaging
WHERE name = 'Cardboard box'
UNION ALL
SELECT stationery_id, 'stationery'
FROM stationery
WHERE description = 'Cardboard box'
UNION ALL
SELECT sales_id, 'sales'
FROM sales
WHERE offer = 'Cardboard box'
```

You'll need to ensure you have the same data type for each column in the result set, and you can use the first statement to set a normalised column name for the result set.

Comment: Thank you Álvaro! For me this notation in mysql-queries is always confusing. Thanks!!